# Spreadsheet summing based on substring match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am struggling with one part of this exercise. I'm able to sum based on one column unique values (i.e. column G). I'm also to extract unique names from columns with multiple names in same cell (column I). What I am not able to do is get work assigned for the person from multiple rows. For simplicity, the work is just divided equally between number of people in that row.

Desired outcome is in column L. Sample sheet to work with is here 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xwv8IV-XNMArSFZEdT8mR-ZbOFHRFFZMfAm7dwm3bbE/edit#gid=741595390

[image: Data example]

Answer (score 1):

Try it as (in J3),

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D$3:D$8)/(LEN(C$3:C$8)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C$3:C$8, " ", ""))+1), --ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I3, C$3:C$8)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. It does work but could you explain it for my education so I can use variations in future!!